# Call a controller in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 3, you could call a controller using the Controller::call method, like so:

`Controller::call('api.items@index', $params);`

I looked through the Controller class in L4 and found this method which seems to replace the older method: callAction(). Though it isn't a static method and I couldn't get it to work. Probably not the right way to do it?

How can I do this in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If I understand right, you are trying to build an API-centric application and want to access the API internally in your web application to avoid making an additional HTTP request (e.g. with cURL). Is that correct?

You could do the following:

```
$request = Request::create('api/items', 'GET', $params);
return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

Notice that, instead of specifying the controller@method destination, you'll need to use the uri route that you'd normally use to access the API externally.

Even better, you can now specify the HTTP verb the request should respond to.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException` error, and the URL that it says was not found is not `api/items` but rather the controller that is making that call.

Comment: Any ideas what it was changed to in L 4.*?

Comment: How to pass parameters as get Request? Parameters are not accessible in method if passed in array?

Comment: See Jason Lewis answer here for how to make it work with Input::get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597420/how-can-i-access-query-string-parameters-for-requests-ive-manually-dispatched-i

Comment: With recent version of PHP, `App::make( \Path\To\Controller::class )->method( $param1, [$param2] );` keeps your IDE aware of what you're doing and allows for easier refactoring, as well as looking cleaner (I hate the strings scattered everywhere in Laravel code)

Answer (score 91):

You may use IoC.

Try this:

```
App::make($controller)->{$action}();
```

Eg:

```
App::make('HomeController')->getIndex();
```

and you may also give params:

```
App::make('HomeController')->getIndex($params);
```

Comment: In this approach no filters are called

Comment: It depends what you need. For a case where you have a route like `/{slug}` and it might be a product or page, you want to call a function that checks the database for the slug and then calls the corresponding controller.

Answer (score 10):

Like Neto said you can user:

```
App::make('HomeController')->getIndex($params);
```

But to send for instance a POST with extra data you could use "merge" method before:

```
$input = array('extra_field1' => 'value1', 'extra_field2' => 'value2');
Input::merge($input);

return App:make('HomeController')->someMethodInController();
```

It works for me!

bye

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way, but you can create a function to do that:

```
function call($controller, $action, $parameters = array())
{
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make($controller);
    return $controller->callAction($app, $app['router'], $action, $parameters);
}

Route::get('/test', function($var = null) use ($params)
{
    return call('TestController', 'index', array($params));
});
```

Comment: Gabriel Koerich this is great! The only problem with this though is that Route::currentRouteAction() is null and in my case I need this information, could you give me your input I created a question at

Comment: Well, can you pass a "name" and the action for this route in a parameter?

Comment: This doesn't work for me - laravel 4.2, the prototype is `callAction($method, $parameters)`, so you don't need to include the `$app`. Also, callAction passes the parameters as arguments, it doesn't set them as Input values.

Comment: At the time I answered this, the method required an instance of Application and Router also. Why would it send it as input values? It is not sending a http request, it is just calling a method. Anyway, you shouldn't use this to call a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Laurent's solution works (though you need a leading `/` and the `$params` you pass to `Request::create` are GET params, and not those handled by Laravel (gotta put them after `api/items/` in the example).

I can't believe there isn't an easier way to do this though (not that it's hard, but it looks kinda hackish to me). Basically, **Laravel 4 doesn't provide an easy way to map a route to a controller using a callback function?** Seriously? This is the most common thing in the world...

I had to do this on one of my projects:

```
Route::controller('players', 'PlayerController');

Route::get('player/{id}{rest?}', function($id)
{
    $request = Request::create('/players/view/' . $id, 'GET');
    return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
})
->where('id', '\d+');
```

Hope I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Looks like you should be using [resourceful controllers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers). What are you doing with the `{rest}` placeholder?

Comment: Resource controllers should do the job indeed (just started using L4 yesterday or so, didn't learn of all the new stuff yet), but I would have liked a more "customizable" way of handling things, just in case. I guess using Request::create is not that bad. (`{rest?}` is there so that there can be stuff right after the ID in the title, for more friendly URLs.) Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$request = Request::create('common_slider', 'GET', $parameters);
return  Controller::getRouter()->dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

For laravel 5.1

Answer (score 0):

It's an Old question. But maybe is usefull. Is there another way.

In your controller: You can declare the function as public static

```
public static function functioNAME(params)
{
    ....
}
```

And then in the Routes file or in the View:

```
ControllerClassName::functionNAME(params);
```