# Laravel 4 Route::dispatch overhead

Tags: performance, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a web application that need to expose Json API for external apps and I'm planning to do an API centric architecture.

So basicly, the app will juste contains view/controllers for the web interface. the controllers will use Route::dispatch to create a request to the api part of the site (another controller in a package, but in the same laravel installation), then parse the result, and create view accordingly.

So I'm wondering what are the drawbacks, performance wise, of using this sort of architecture?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know how the framework handle it performance wise. Knowing how behave the thing on top of which you build your house is sometimes important, especially when you're at the architecture design stage.

Comment: A -1 and a vote to close as not constructive? I'm not sure that's warranted here. This question is asking for "the drawbacks, performance wise, of using this sort of architecture", which to me is very specific and can be answered clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each controller is writing the logic to internally dispatch another  request then I'd consider abstracting that away from the controller and in to your own dispatcher. I doubt there would be a huge performance overhead. The application (as far as I know) doesn't get booted twice so you don't have to worry about that.

The only thing you need to be aware of is the input for the main request being used. Something you should take into account inside your dispatcher. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16600493/280329) for more information.

You can also read more on [consuming your own API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api).