# Laravel: Load method in another controller without changing the url

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have this route: `Route::controller('/', 'PearsController');` Is it possible in Laravel to get the PearsController to load a method from another controller so the URL doesn't change?

For example:

```
// route:
Route::controller('/', 'PearsController');


// controllers
class PearsController extends BaseController {

    public function getAbc() {
        // How do I load ApplesController@getSomething so I can split up
        // my methods without changing the url? (retains domain.com/abc)
    }

}

class ApplesController extends BaseController {

    public function getSomething() {
        echo 'It works!'
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205239/call-a-controller-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use (L3 only)

```
Controller::call('ApplesController@getSomething');
```

In `L4` you can use

```
$request = Request::create('/apples', 'GET', array());
return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

In this case, you have to define a route for `ApplesController`, something like  this

```
Route::get('/apples', 'ApplesController@getSomething'); // in routes.php
```

In the `array()` you can pass arguments if required.

Comment: How to pass parameters as get Request? Parameters are not accessible in method if passed in array?

Comment: It seems, that POST parameters in Laravel are not redefined and Input::all() still reads parameters from an original request, not the one we rerouted to.

Comment: `Input::all()` reads all input sources including `FILES` array.

Answer (score 27):

( by [neto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413579/neto) in [Call a controller in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205239/call-a-controller-in-laravel-4) )

Use IoC...

```
App::make($controller)->{$action}();
```

Eg:

```
App::make('HomeController')->getIndex();
```

and you may also give params

```
App::make('HomeController')->getIndex($params);
```

Comment: Used this method for constructing a base controller in order to use some shared variables.

Comment: But I get the 'Method [myMethod] does not exist'

Answer (score 11):

You should not. In MVC, controllers should not 'talk' to each other, if they have to share 'data' they should do it using a model, wich is the type of class responsible for data sharing in your app. Look:

```
// route:
Route::controller('/', 'PearsController');


// controllers
class PearsController extends BaseController {

    public function getAbc() 
    {
        $something = new MySomethingModel;

        $this->commonFunction();

        echo $something->getSomething();
    }

}

class ApplesController extends BaseController {

    public function showSomething() 
    {
        $something = new MySomethingModel;

        $this->commonFunction();

        echo $something->getSomething();
    }

}

class MySomethingModel {

    public function getSomething() 
    {
        return 'It works!';
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

What you can do instead is to use BaseController to create common functions to be shared by all your controllers. Take a look at `commonFunction` in `BaseController` and how it's used in the two controllers.

```
abstract class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function commonFunction() 
    {
       // will do common things 
    }

}

class PearsController extends BaseController {

    public function getAbc() 
    {
        return $this->commonFunction();
    }

}

class ApplesController extends BaseController {

    public function showSomething() 
    {
        return $this->commonFunction();
    }

}
```

Comment: "You should not" ...  Okay, but I don't want to rewrite cool/working functions. How do I then write functions I can re-use in both controllers?

Comment: Reuse functions in both controllers (right) completely different from making two controllers talk each other (wrong). Edited the answer to add `commonFunction()` used in both controllers.

Answer (score 8):

if you were in `AbcdController` and trying to access method `public function test()` which exists in `OtherController` you could just do:

```
$getTests = (new OtherController)->test();
```

This should work in L5.1

Comment: and if i am in /name/abaController then how can i use it ?

Comment: how to pass parameters :-)