# One route and call two controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have these two routes on routes.php

```
Route::post('view', 'LivefeedController@liveversion');
//test new view.
Route::post('testview', 'TestController@testversion');
```

What I am trying to do is call both controllers and methods using 1 route. So if someone goes to /view both of liveversion and testversion are called. What would be the best way to do this please?

Comment: From LivefeedController@liveversion() call TestController@testversion() or vice versa (as you wish).

Comment: how would I do that ? if you know please

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034616/laravel-load-method-in-another-controller-without-changing-the-url

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Just don't..

Comment: Calling a controller from a controller is an anti-pattern... just move your logic to a service class that you can use in your controller code...

Answer (score 2):

You might Redirect from the first controller to second after finishing its job, for example in LivefeedController liveversion method you can redirect like that: 
`return Redirect::action('TestController@testversion');`

Here is the [documentation on Laravel Redirects](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects), though as it was pointed out in comments - thats not a good thing to do (redirect from one POST action to another POST action).