# Calling a controller in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller prefixed with a namespace. How can I execute that controller? Without necessarily make a Request object on the fly. What should I do?

I have found this solution on the net:

```
$app = app();
            $controller = $app->make(ucfirst("MyNamespace")."\\".ucfirst($controller_name)."Controller");
            return $controller->callAction($controller, $parameters = array());
I get an error that says `callAction()`'s first parameter must be of type `Container`.
```

How should I execute a controller in Laravel from inside another controller?

Comment: Why would you call a controller not from a route..? This is most likely a clear indicator that you need to extract that logic i.e. in a service class.

Comment: also, why are you doing $controller->callAction($controller, $parameters = array()). There is no need to pass a reference to itself to the callAction method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034616/laravel-load-method-in-another-controller-without-changing-the-url