# How to call a Laravel controller's method from other class

Tags: php, laravel

I need to call a public method of a Laravel controller from another class.

Given this controller method:

```php
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function examplefunction(){

       //stuff
        
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in my project I need to do this:

```php
public function otherfunctioninothercontroller(){
    // I need to run MyController::examplefunction() here
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: if this is the case, you should probably think about extracting the function out to somewhere it should be, like into the helpers or models if applicable.

Comment: You should _not_ call a controller method from within another controller method. This is a clean sign you need to re-factor.

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034616/laravel-load-method-in-another-controller-without-changing-the-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I have Controller1 and Controller2. I want to call a function of Controller1 from inside a function placed  in Controller2.

```
// Controller1.php
class Controller1 {
    public static function f1()
    {

    }
}
```

And on the other controller:

```
// Controller2.php
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller1;

class Controller2 {
    public function f2()
    {
        return Controller1::f1();
    }
}
```

Points to be noted:

1. f1() is declared static

Answer (score 19):

1. First way

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\OtherController;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //Calling a method that is from the OtherController
        $result = (new OtherController)->method();
    }
}
```

2. Second way

```php
app('App\Http\Controllers\OtherController')->method();
```

Both way you can get another controller function.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply instantiate the controller and call the desired method as follows

FirstController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class FirstController extends Controller {
    public function examplefunction() {
        // TODO: implement functionality
    }
}
```

SecondController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SecondController extends Controller {
    public function test() {
        $object = new FirstController();
        $object->examplefunction();
    }
}
```

Now, after i've answered the question, i would like to add the following comment:

Controllers are classes, all rules that applies to normal classes can be applied to them

However, instantiating a controller directly inside another controller to call a desired method signifies a problem in your design for the following 2 reasons:

1. A controller cannot obtain an instance of another controller directly
2. Controller should contain as little business logic as possible, and if possible **none**

The closest possible solution to what you want (**WITHOUT BREAKING MVC**) is to make an HTTP request to the route that points to the desired method (using cURL, for example) and read the response as the returned data

But this still doesn't make much sense in this scenario because after all you're making an HTTP request from a method in a controller in your project on your server to a method in a controller in your project on your server, seems like unnecessary overhead, right ?

As i said earlier, a controller should contain as little business logic as possible because the logic should stay inside specialized classes (commonly known as **Service Classes**), and when a processing is requested the controller simply delegates the job of processing to the appropriate service class which does the processing and returns the results to the controller which in turn sends it back as a response

Now imagine if you've the following scenario:

We've got an application that consists of 3 functionalities:

- A user can register an account from web application
- There's a mobile application that talks to an API to register a user
- There's an admin panel, which he can use to add new user

Obviously you need to create 3 controllers, but those controllers contains repeated logic, would you copy/paste the code everywhere ?

Why not encapsulate this logic inside a service class and call it from the controller when needed ?

Answer (score 2):

If they are not in the same folder, place `use namespace\to\ExampleClass;` on top of your file, then you are able to instantiate your controller.

Answer (score 0):

A call to a  controller from inside  another controller is a bad idea. There is no sense of meaning of controllers then. You should just redirect to web.php to save safe whole  architecture like this:

```
class MyController {
  public function aSwitchCaseFunction(Request $requestPrm){
    ...
    //getting path string from request here
    ...
    switch($myCase){
        case CASE_1:
             return redirect()->route('/a/route/path');
        ....
    }
  }
}
```