# Laravel 5 route returns view but changes url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im not even sure if this is possible but what I am trying to do is this. I store different page modules in a database. When someone goes to a page with one of these modules, the pageController recognizes its a module and ( using the redirect path stored with this module in the DB ) redirects them to a get route which is how I know what info to pull and put on the page.

For instance, if someone was to go to /photo-album the pageController would recognize that was a page module and returns the redirect ( redirect/photo/albums ) and then redirects them to that route.

```
Route::get('redirect/photo/albums', ['uses' =>'PageController@getPhotoAlbums']);
```

The problem is the url then becomes /redirect/photo/albums. I would like it to maintain /photo-album

The reason I am doing it this way is because there will be several modules stored and each one will contain different things ( think blog, photo albums, video gallery etc. ). I need the redirect to figure out what goes on that page and what view to show. In this case PageController@getPhotoAlbums goes to the getPhotoAlbums method, pulls the photos and serves up the photoalbums view.

There may be a better way to do this and i'm open to it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll put this as an answer and hope it helps:

You really shouldn't get data from another controller. All your data should be available in the Eloquent model. This is important to the 'MVC' architecture.

There is more discussion on this here: [Laravel: Load method in another controller without changing the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034616/laravel-load-method-in-another-controller-without-changing-the-url)

So essentially, when your controller recognises it as a page module it should pull that data from the DB using Eloquent and then pass that to a View. That will mean that the original request URL is still retained.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for answering. I went through that link and dod some more research on this and you are 100% right. I knew the path I was on was not right. I put everything in the model and used a simple if statement which returns the correct view. Problem solved.