# Laravel 4: Redirect a post request to different controller method

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a controller like below,
**MyController:**

```
public function methodA() {
    return Input::get('n')*10;
}  

public function methodB() {
    return Input::get('n')*20;
}
```

I want to call the a method inside **MyController** according to **POST** value.

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/', function(){
    $flag = Input::get('flag');
    if($flag == 1) {
        //execute methodA and return the value
    } else {
        //execute methodB and return the value
    }
});
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: You can use a double colon after `Route` for a start :D

Comment: Just a wild suggestion, why not use an extra url parameter and save yourself this trouble

Comment: Do you mean accoring to the url value (that is sumbitted via POST) or according to the $_POST parameter value?

Comment: @Yani according to $_POST parameter

Comment: @palatok OK, please see my answer below. should work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I think would be a cleaner solution is to send your post request to different URLs depending on your flag and have different routes for each, that map to your controller methods

```
Route::post('/flag', 'MyController@methodA');
Route::post('/', 'MyController@methodB);
```

## EDIT:

To do it your way, you can use this snippet

```
Route:post('/', function(){
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make('MyController');
    $flag = Input::get('flag');
    if($flag == 1) {
        return $controller->callAction('methodA', $parameters = array());
    } else {
        return $controller->callAction('methodB', $parameters = array());
    }
});
```

**[Source](http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/call-controller-from-route-closure)**

**OR**

```
Route:post('/', function(){
    $flag = Input::get('flag');
    if($flag == 1) {
        App::make('MyController')->methodA();
    } else {
        App::make('MyController')->methodB();
    }
});
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17385344/2415293)**

And just to note - I have absolutely zero practical experience with Laravel, I just searched and found this.

Comment: i was asked to do it in other way

Answer (score 3):

**This is for Laravel 4.x. When using Laravel 5, you need to add Namespaces... The question is about Laravel 4**

---

The `Route::controller()` method is what you need.

Your routes files should look like this:

```
Route:post('/', function(){
    $flag = Input::get('flag');
    if($flag == 1) {
        Route::controller('/', 'MyController@methodA');
    } else {
        Route::controller('/', 'MyController@methodB');
    }
});
```

And the methods would look like this:

```
public function methodA() {
    return Input::get('n') * 10;
}  

public function methodB() {
    return Input::get('n') * 20;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting ReflectionException (-1) Class  does not exist

Comment: This is for Laravel 4.x. When using Laravel 5, you need to add Namespaces... The question is about Laravel 4

Answer (score 3):

According to your answer in the comments, your need 1 url and deciding which method to use based on the $_POST value. This is what you need:

In your `Routes.php` file, add a general method that

```
Route::post('/', 'MyController@landingMethod);
```

In your `MyController` file:

```
public function landingMethod() {
    $flag = Input::get('flag');
    return $flag == 1 ? $this->methodA() : $this->methodB();//just a cleaner way than doing `if...else` to my taste
} 

public function methodA() { //can also be private/protected method if you're not calling it directly
    return Input::get('n') * 10;
}  

public function methodB() {//can also be private/protected method if you're not calling it directly
    return Input::get('n') * 20;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice solution . But actually i have multiple Controller, and i don't think calling a controller from another controller is not so pretty.Anyway thanks for your kind reply