# Call a method from one controller inside another

Tags: laravel, methods, controller, external, laravel-5

Is it possible to call a method from one controller inside another controller in Laravel 5 (regardless the http method used to access each method)?

Comment: The L4 technique at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205239/call-a-controller-in-laravel-4 will probably still work.

Comment: You sure somehow could do that, but if you're in the situation where you have to do that, that's a big code smell! Extract the functionality you need into a separate class and then inject it into your controllers.

Comment: This is a big no-no! You should refractor that and create a class for that purpose, or an abstract class and extend all your controllers from it

Comment: I'f you can, I'd put whatever function you need to call into a trait and use that trait in your controllers which need it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is how I have done it. Use the `use` keyword to make the OtherController available. Then you can call a method from that class on instantiation.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\OtherController;

class MyController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        //Calling a method that is from the OtherController
        $result = (new OtherController)->method();
    }
}
```

Also check out the concept of a [Command](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus) in Laravel. It might give you more flexibility than the method above.

Comment: This is what I thought of doing but wondering how to pass `Inputs`?

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\TargetsController;

// this controller contains a function to call
class OrganizationController extends Controller {
    public function createHolidays() {
        // first create the reference of this controller
        $b = new TargetsController();
        $mob = 9898989898;
        $msg = "i am ready to send a msg";

        // parameter will be same 
        $result = $b->mytesting($msg, $mob);
        log::info('my testing function call with return value' . $result);
    }
}

// this controller calls it
class TargetsController extends Controller {
    public function mytesting($msg, $mob) {
        log::info('my testing function call');
        log::info('my mob:-' . $mob . 'my msg:-' . $msg);
        $a = 10;
        return $a;
    }
}
```

Comment: This creates just another controller and calls its method. Also the direction of the call is reverse even to what's written in comments