# How to use multiple routes that link to same page in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have 2 controllers. One manages category and other slider. They have no relation between them. They are on same homepage in different sections. So I want to show both category and slider value that is there in database.

I tried

```
Route::get('/', ['uses'=>'SliderController@homepage','as'=>'homepage']);
Route::get('/', ['uses'=>'CategoryController@homepage','as'=>'categoryHomepage']);
```

**If I do that the second one is overwriting the first one.**

**Is there a way from which I can pass both routes so that I can use both values in my homepage.**

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you could try to call one method in the other method to get all data at one place and then set the route to that method accordingly

Comment: @MehravishTemkar can you give a reference site as I don't know how to share values between controllers.

Comment: it's a bit odd, you had exact same `url` and same method, but expect it to behave differently. is there any criteria for it to pass request to the first controller or the second one? if so, you might want to use `middleware` or just multiplex on controller level as Mehravish Temkar suggested.

Comment: @BagusTesa I kept same method name for simplicity. Can you tell me how to implement it or a site where it has implemented it. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a job for ajax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750913/call-a-method-from-one-controller-inside-another try these and also refer laravel docs

Comment: @Phoenix, *can you give a reference site as I don't know how to share values between controllers* you could call another controller's function just like calling a class' function. just instantiate target controller properly and call its method.

Comment: just a bit curious, for what reason `Route::get('/',...) ` twice? (same url, same method, two different controller)

Comment: @BagusTesa I have 2 controller One manages category and other slider. They have no relation between them. Just they are on same homepage in different sections. So I want to show both category and slider value that is there in database. That is why I did that

Comment: *on same homepage in different sections* - is it ajax?

Comment: @BagusTesa No. Its completely laravel website with php for backend and bootstrap for frontend. I didnt use any javascript or ajax yet.

Comment: what you can do is,  call either of controller's function in another, ex : CategoryController's homepage() can be called from  SliderController's homePage() and then pass data from both the function to blade

Comment: @BagusTesa Html has <section> tags so I meant that one section has slider and other has category I needed to get its value from database

Comment: @kapil.dev yes I will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091998/laravel-how-to-use-2-controllers-in-1-route).

**1 Single route**

```
Route::get('/home', ['uses'=>'SliderController@index','as'=>'homepage']);
```

**2 Create a data passing controller**

```
use View;

class SliderController extends Controller {

    private $repository;

    public function __construct(DataRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function index(DataRepository $repository)
    {
        return View::make('home.index')->with('data', $this-repository->getData());
    }

}
```

**3 `DataRepository` class fetch there records**

```
class DataRepository {

    public getData()
    {
        $data = array();

        $data['category'] = Category::all();

        $data['slider'] = Slider::all();

        return $data;
    }

}
```

After above three steps, DataRepository will automatically inject data to your controller. Reference taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091998/laravel-how-to-use-2-controllers-in-1-route).